# manage.py runserver throws an ImportError with my appname, MacPorts issue on OSX?

Tags: python, django, macos

I've been developing a Django app for weeks locally on OSX 10.6.3. Recently, I rebooted my machine and went to start my development environment up.

Here's the error:

> cm:myApp cm$ python manage.py runserver
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "manage.py", line 11, in  execute_manager(settings)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 360, in execute_manager
>       setup_environ(settings_mod)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 343, in setup_environ
>       project_module = import_module(project_name)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
>       **import**(name)
>   ImportError: No module named myapp

I'm pretty new to Django / Python.

Digging around, it's possible that this might be due to MacPorts. Initially, I had a rough time getting Django up and running and I no longer remember if I'm using the Django from a MacPorts install or from easy_install. How do I tell? (I'd prefer not to reinstall everything).

Also, why is the camel casing in my app name gone in the ImportError message? When I search for "myapp" in my django project, I don't find it without camelcase anywhere.

And what causes MacPorts to work for a while but then break?

As a few other details, from settings.py:

> INSTALLED_APPS = (
>       'django.contrib.auth',
>       'django.contrib.contenttypes',
>       'django.contrib.sessions',
>       'django.contrib.sites',
>       'django.contrib.admin',
>       'south',
>       'registration',
>       'pypaypal',
>       'notifier',
>       'myApp.batches',
>   )

Answer (score 0):

To tell where you're currently running Django from, open up a Python shell and do:

```
import django
print django.__path__
```

which should show you the path to the Django directory.

You might also want to do this from with the Python shell:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

This should show you all the directories on the current PythonPath, which might help in your debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is very bizarre and I don't know what happened... but here's what fixed:

1. I open terminal and bash isn't recognizing any commands (python, vi, etc)
2. I restart machine, still not recognizing any commands
3. I look at my $PATH and /usr/bin is missing
4. I add /usr/bin to $PATH
5. I open vi and modify my profile to add /usr/bin
6. vi works, python works
7. python manage.py runserver works

How did /usr/bin get removed from my bash profile?

Comment: check your __ init __.py" (that was my problem)